# List of albums from MediaStore to adapter/listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter, mediastore

I am able to make list of all songs in mediastore, but I also want to sort them by artists/ albums/folders/genres/playlists.

I usually query own databases with cursor, but this is not effective in this case and I have to use adapters. I am able to query that by changing parameters, but I don´t know how to group it in adapter (I couldn´t find how to add/use GROUPBY), meaning I need every artists/albums/folders/.. in adapter only once, not for each song.

I tried to search over internet and I didn´t find answer. I also found some topics here, but still it is not clear for me. Therefore I would like to ask you to show me that on this [example](http://android-er.blogspot.cz/2012/02/get-info-of-specified-item-in.html):

```
package com.exercise.AndroidListMedia;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidListMediaActivity extends ListActivity {

 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String[] from = {
    MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
  int[] to = {
    android.R.id.text1};

  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
  cursor.moveToPosition(position);

  String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
  String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
  String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
  String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
  int duration = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

  String info = "_ID: " + _id + "\n"
 + "TITLE: " + title + "\n"
 + "ARTIST: " + artist + "\n"
 + "ALBUM: " + album + "\n"
 + "DURATION: " + duration/1000 + "s";

  Toast.makeText(this, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: What I did to solve this was created a class called `CursorToListAdapter` it is not a sibling to `ArrayAdapter` it means adapter as in you fit it to a Cursor, and you can use it like a list. You can then pass this to an ArrayAdapter (subclassing `getView` of course) to display it, would a guide about this help you? (It's a very good design pattern, but I'm not writing about it if I've misread the question :P)

Comment: Hi Alec, yes, if you will be so kind, I would appreciate guidance : )

Answer (score 7):

This gets you all albums:

```
public Cursor getAlbumAlbumcursor(Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    String where = null;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID; 
    final String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID; 
    final String album_name =MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;
    final String[]columns={_id,album_name, artist};
    cursor = cr.query(uri,columns,where,null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

This gets you all tracks:

```
public Cursor getTrackTrackcursor(Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID; 
    final String track_no =MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String track_name =MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
    final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
    final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
    final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver cr =  context.getContentResolver();
    final String[]columns={track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,album, duration, path, year, composer};
    cursor = cr.query(uri,columns,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

This gets you all playlists:

```
 public  Cursor getandroidPlaylistcursor(Context context,Cursor cursor)
 {
     ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
     final Uri uri=MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
     final String id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
     final String name = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;
     final String[]columns = {id,name};
     final String criteria = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME.length() + " > 0 " ;
     final Cursor crplaylists = resolver.query(uri, columns, criteria, null,name + "    `ASC");
     return crplaylists;
 }
```

Note the different uri's  MediaStore.Audio.Media for tracks, MediaStore.Audio.Albums for album detail, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists for playlists.

The last parameter in the cr.query is the sort order, My playlist shows an example:  name + "    `ASC" which sorts by playlist name.
I hope this helps

I have developed an app which allows you to manage/create playlists and uses these techniques.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyingdutchman.playlistmanager&hl=en
or search Google Play for Playlist Manager.

Comment: The added criteria `final String criteria = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME.length() + " > 0 "` does nothing because the result is always `"4 > 0"`. Better checking the name is different from empty string.

Comment: I have realised that passing the Cursor cursor is pointless, it just needs the context

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ArrayList<SongBeen> getAlbumList() {

            ArrayList<SongBeen> albumList=new ArrayList<SongBeen>();
            ContentResolver musicResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri =    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.**Albums**.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
            if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){

                int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);


                //add songs to list
                do {
                    SongBeen been=new SongBeen();


                    been.setId(musicCursor.getLong(idColumn));
                    been.setAlbum(musicCursor.getString(albumColumn));
                    been.setArtist(musicCursor.getString(artistColumn));


                    albumList.add(been);
            } 
                while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return albumList;

        }
```

Note:

changing the album or any other thing we can get all

Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;